# Creating flash like animations using Canvas and Html 5

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I have recently visited http://www.sublimetext.com and on their home page there is a flash like animation to represent the features of their editor. I wanted to know if it was a loop of images? or gif or a small .mp4 video. Can anyone give me a basic understanding how I could replicate that sort of functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an article on how that page was made [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/~jps/animated_gifs_the_hard_way.html), along with a link to the "[encoder](https://github.com/sublimehq/anim_encoder)".